# Sharekit2.0 share crash in iOS4: NSAssert(vc.presentingViewController == nil, @"vc must not be in the view hierarchy now

Tags: ios, sharekit

I have latest Sharekit2.0 included in my project. It's OK on iOS5 and iOS6.However in iOS4, I could not finish  share to twitter because of an issue: "    NSAssert(vc.presentingViewController == nil, @"vc must not be in the view hierarchy now"); //ios4 and older", which is included in SHK.m

I know it's a cause of absence of TWTweetComposeViewController which is used to input share text/picture. However, I still don't know how to implement it and support ios4 ?

I appreciate if somebody could help me on it and better have lines of demo code :). It's better not to change the Sharekit submodule.

Liang

Comment: interesting. The assert is due to the resolved bug, when one view started to present itself, while still being in the view hierarchy. Apparently this happens in iOS4. Can you temporarily comment the line, if sharing will continue normally?

Comment: Also, during what phase of sharing this showed up? Was it after authentication, before presenting edit view for user?

Comment: Why do you still need to support iOS4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed ShareKit, please update. I do not have iOS4 device around to test, so please let me know, if it works. However, please answer my comments.

Comment: So many thanks. It's working fine now in iOS4.0 after update. And answer your comments:
1.  I have to support iOS4 since it's a strong requirement from customer
2. it happened after authentication and before presenting edit view for user